# Finding maximum frequency of a specific column

Tags: python

Input file,

```
ID,ROLLNO,AMOUNT,COUNT
1,0700,1500,10
2,900,500,3
3,0700,500,10
4,900,150,9
5,0700,1000,10
6,01620,80,5
7,0700,1000,10
8,0700,1000,10
```

I have to find those `ROLLNO`s and `AMOUNT` that is having the most `COUNT` wrt a particular `AMOUNT`. For example, for `ROLLNO` `900` `AMOUNT` `150` having most `COUNT` so that should come in the output. 
Also if a `ROLLNO` is having same `COUNT` values then, the corresponding `AMOUNT`S must be totaled to give result. For example, for `ROLLNO` `0700` all `COUNT`s are same so its `AMOUNT` should be `1500+500+1000+1000+1000 = 5000`;

The expected output would be something like this,

```
ID,ROLLNO,COUNT,AMOUNT
6,900,9,150
5,01620,5,80
2,0700,10,5000
```

What would be the best way to do this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: My bad. ID is of no importance here. I just put some values, that's all.

Comment: You can use pandas `groupby` and `sum` methods.

Comment: Your expected output `ID`s don't seem to correlate to your input?

Comment: @JonClements: My bad. IDs need not be taken into consideration much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pandas` are viable, this should do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv')
df.groupby(['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'])['AMOUNT'].sum()\
  .reset_index()\
  .sort_values(by=['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'], ascending=False)\
  .drop_duplicates('ROLLNO')
#   ROLLNO  COUNT  AMOUNT
#3    1620      5      80
#2     900      9     150
#0     700     10    5000
```

Please take note that this doesn't solve for ID as it is not clear how you determine that.

If you have massive `csv` file you can take advantage of `chunksize` parameter:

```
chunksize = 10

prefinal = pd.DataFrame()

for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    grouped = chunk.groupby(['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'])['AMOUNT'].sum()\
                   .reset_index()\
                   .sort_values(by=['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'], ascending=False)\
                   .drop_duplicates('ROLLNO')
    prefinal = pd.concat([prefinal, grouped], ignore_index=True)

final = prefinal.groupby(['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'])['AMOUNT'].sum()\
                .reset_index()\
                .sort_values(by=['ROLLNO', 'COUNT'], ascending=False)\
                .drop_duplicates('ROLLNO')
```

The example above will read the file 10 rows at a time and process them, finally processing all of them combined.

Comment: is there any way i can do this operation in chunks? please let me know

Comment: @Marek Could you please be more precise? Do you mean separating file into chunks or splitting the process into separate steps rather than method chaining?

Comment: I meant seperating the file into chunks as my input data is quite huge. Kindly suggest a way to handle that

Comment: @Marek Can you please check the edit. Set your `chunksize` to number that will suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.groupby` from the standard library.

You can use `pandas` thereafter if you require specific formatting.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""ID,ROLLNO,AMOUNT,COUNT
1,0700,1500,10
2,900,500,3
3,0700,500,10
4,900,150,9
5,0700,1000,10
6,01620,80,5
7,0700,1000,10
8,0700,1000,10""")

d = defaultdict(int)

with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for line in reader:
        d[(line['ROLLNO'], int(line['COUNT']))] += int(line['AMOUNT'])

sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), reverse=True)
res = [next(j) for _, j in groupby(sorted_d, key=lambda x: x[0][0])]

[(('900', 9), 150),
 (('0700', 10), 5000),
 (('01620', 5), 80)]
```

Comment: If you sort in reverse, you can then use `next(j)` instead of building a list and taking the last item...

Comment: I'd probably also use a `csv.DictReader` so that you 1) don't have to skip  headers and 2) access it such as `line['ROLLNO']` etc... if one wanted to be a bit more explicit as to what's going on in there... (Or maybe even just drop that bit and go for `d[line['ROLLNO'], int(line['COUNT'])] += int(line['AMOUNT'])`...

Comment: @JonClements, Agree, that's indeed better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to plain python, you can use dictionaries:

```
file = open("input.txt", "r")
dct = {}
headers = file.readline()
for line in file:
    lst = line.split(",")
    if lst[1] not in dct:
        dct[lst[1]] = lst
        continue
    if dct[lst[1]][3] < lst[3]:
        dct[lst[1]] = lst

print headers
for row in dct.values():
    print ','.join(row)
```

Update: Since this may not be clear, making the dictionary key be your ROLLNO value enforces the unique constraint: for each ROLLNO value that occurs, your dictionary dct will story the row with the largest value in the fourth column (COUNT)